# Notification blanks my activity

Tags: android, notifications

I've a service that pops a notification if there are some news and if the user is not using my app... When the user touches on the notification, I want it to bring them on the main page, and I declare it using a PendingIntent...
But then, my application doesn't show any fragment, though they are visible and not hidden..
This is the code I used to show the notification

```
Intent inte = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, inte, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                    NotificationManager man = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    man.notify(0,builder.build());
```

And this is my onCreate. I think it has something to do with my SaveInstanceState but can't understand what.
My onCreate adds fragments only if there is no instance state saved and then shows or hides some of the fragments.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_left,mChatListFragment);
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_left,mQuestionListFragment);
            transaction.hide(mQuestionListFragment);
            transaction.show(mChatListFragment);
            if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_right) != null) {    // two pane layout
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_right,mChatDetailsFragment);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_right,mChatNewFragment);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_right,mQuestionDetailsFragment);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_right,mQuestionNewFragment);
                transaction.hide(mQuestionDetailsFragment);
                transaction.show(mChatNewFragment);
                transaction.hide(mChatDetailsFragment);
                transaction.hide(mQuestionNewFragment);
            }
            else {
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_left,mChatDetailsFragment);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_left,mChatNewFragment);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_left,mQuestionDetailsFragment);
                transaction.add(R.id.fragment_left,mQuestionNewFragment);
                transaction.hide(mQuestionDetailsFragment);
                transaction.hide(mChatNewFragment);
                transaction.hide(mChatDetailsFragment);
                transaction.hide(mQuestionNewFragment);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        }
```

Comment: this issue has nothing to do with the PendingIntent or the notification, it's probably an issue with your activity, please add the `onCreate`, `onNewIntent` method's code

Comment: Whats your issue with notification please specify in detail by step

Comment: @Rajan Bhavsar I think he described it allready pretty detailed.

Comment: i asked to Luigi Bana not to you so don't be oversmart ok Dear

Comment: Please show us the home activity code

Comment: @Rajan Bhavsar haha he has gioven the notification code :everythink is fine...and he described what happens: his homeactivity is not loading like usually so shut up pls eat some curry instead

Comment: May the problem be the registration of a broadcastReceiver?